# PyQGIS import csv- QGIS 3.4

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3

This is seemingly pretty simple.  I have a csv file I want to add to the map. It is comma delimited and there is no lat/lon information. I will join it to a shapefile later. I used other examples from stackoverflow and [this documentation in the QGIS cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html) to do it. I can add it with the following code:

```
uri = 'file:///Users/ep9k/Desktop/SandraMonson/CountByZip.csv?delimiter=,'
csv_file = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Patient Data', 'delimitedtext')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(csv_file)
```

This adds the file to the map. But in the attribute table it reads all data as column headers. The attribute table looks like this:
[image]

ZipCode, PatientCount, StateOrProvince should be the column headers, with data below. How can I read the first line as column headers and the rest as data in those columns?

Another thought I have, after looking at the QGIS cookbook documentation, I went into [PyQGIS API documentation](https://qgis.org/api/) and into Module>Core Library> and looked for QgsVectorLayer and QgsProject, and it seems counterintuitive as a csv file is not a vector layer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer my own question using this helpful thread about a related question: [Trouble loading non-spatial data via CSV using Python for standalone script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183358/trouble-loading-non-spatial-data-via-csv-using-python-for-standalone-script?rq=1)

It looks like my csv file was formatted incorrectly. The file was originally an excel file (.xls) and I saved it as a CSV file with utf-8 formatting. QGIS didn't like something about that so I re-saved my file as a plain ".csv" with no formatting.

However, I had not found an example for QGIS 3.x of importing a non-spatial (without lat/lon coordinates) .csv so maybe this can serve as an example of how to do that.