# Add spatial csv-layer in QGIS3 using Python3 code

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, csv

I need to add a spatial csv-file with a specific path (folder and file name) in QGIS3x using a python script.
I have tried:
[PyQGIS import csv- QGIS 3.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302948/pyqgis-import-csv-qgis-3-4/303213#303213)

```
uri = "file:///C:/users/heubacha/Test.csv?type=csv&delimiter=;&detectTypes=yes&xField=X_Wert_Pos&yField=Y_Wert_Pos&crs=epsg:25832&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no"
mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Test', 'delimited text')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

no luck with that...warning: invalid data provider delimited text.

[Trouble loading non-spatial data via CSV using Python for standalone script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183358)
was not getting me anywhere either, because I need to add the path as a string somewhere in the coding, and that's not described there.

Comment: 'delimited text' is not correct,you need write 'delimitedtext'

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! You made my day :)